# Adminlte multi select searching display in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, adminlte

I am using [Adminlte 3 Multiple (.select2-purple)](https://adminlte.io/themes/dev/AdminLTE/pages/forms/advanced.html) in laravel 6, and I got a error like this

I don't know why searching... is showing

[image]

Here's my code:
**VIEW**

```
<div class="col-md">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Technician</label>
      <div class="select2-purple">
        <select class="select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select a Technician" data- 
                  dropdown-css-class="select2-purple" style="width: 100%;">
          @foreach($stations as $station)
            <option id="{{ $station->id }}">{{ $station->name }}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$('.select2').select2()
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
   public function totaltestperform(){
      $stations = \DB::table('stations')
         ->select('id','station')
         ->orderby('id')
         ->get();
     return view("analytic/total_test_perform",compact('stations'));
```

}

Here's the output of station variable when I use `dd($stations);`

[image]

Comment: can you please share the output of  $stations variable

Comment: @Sehdev I update my code with image

Comment: You dropdown image showing "Select a Station" but your dropdown code is showing "Select a Technician". It seems you posted wrong code

Comment: @Sehdev sorry before I crop the picture I forgot to change the placeholder and label so it doesn't matter. the code is correct it just a place holder

Comment: try to add value property of each option like `<option value="{{$station->id}}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong: `<option **id="{{ $station->id }}"**>{{ $station->name }}</option>`

Use: `<option value="{{ $station->id }}">{{ $station->name }}</option>`

Comment: the option does not take id as an attribute  in replacement of value